# A permutation approach of Lilavati Book

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Here is the  Bhaskaracharya's Lilavati book by translated John Taylor,1816.

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=0KMIAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=tr#v=onepage&q&f=false

I am looking at permutation and combination concepts in it.

Please look at page Section IV Permutation , page 57 and 58. The book says Gayatri foot consists of 6 syllables and it has permutations called 1,6,15,20,15,6,1 .
But its strange and suggestive that in calculation method it is exactly the binomial coefficients and it's pascal triangle of the 6th power binomial expansion.
So i think at first Bhaskaracharya thought a permutation problem  background treated as a combination. Is it possible? I am a little confused.

I was only looking for  well-established resource that gives a nice and instructive commentary on binomial coefficients and combinations. Maybe you can give and suggest  a part from a good and old resource or from  this Lilavati's book.

Thanks for good and useful comments.

Comment: Is [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) or [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) what you are looking for?

Comment: @user2661923 of course:) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear that the word "permutation" is not used in the text in our modern sense; it just means possibility for the configuration. And in this case a configuration is a way to compose a "foot" of six syllables from long or short syllables. That number would be $2^6$, but for some reason (that is not explained in the text) one appears to count grouping by total number of short (or maybe instead long) syllables, given a sequence of numbers that is row 6 of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: It's for composing poetry. A long syllable is as long as two short syllables—this is important in Sanskrit prosody—and the grouping is by the length of the line.